# Is there a way to get the Title of the selected item from another component in React Native

Tags: react-native, mobile, react-component

I have two different components "HomePage" & "ListItemCA"

In HomePage, I have a **FlatList** and a modal popup

```
<FlatList
data={ listData}
keyExtractor={list => list.Title}
renderItem={({ item }) => <ListItemCA data={item} onLongPress={openModal} />} 
/>
```

and each list item is called from another component **ListItemCA**

```
function ListItemCA({data, onLongPress}) {

    return (
        <TouchableOpacity onLongPress={onLongPress} >
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text style={styles.title}>{data.Title}</Text>
            <View style={styles.metaContainer}>
                <Text style={styles.meta}>{( data.totalMonths != null ? data.totalMonths : '0' )} Months</Text>
                <Text style={styles.meta}>{( data.members != null ? data.members.length : '0' )} Members</Text>
            </View>
        </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    );
}
```

**What I want to acheive?**

I want to get the selected list item title on my HomePage component. When a user longpress on a list item that title should be displayed on a modal popup. How do I pass the selected list item title to the HomePage component using longpress?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by passing(return) parameter from your component like this -

```
function ListItemCA({data, onLongPress}) {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity onLongPress={() => {
        onLongPress(data.Title);
        //return data.Title when onLongPressed clicked
      }}>
        <View style={styles.container}>
          ...
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
}
```

then get it in props -

```
<FlatList
   data={listData}
   keyExtractor={list => list.Title}
   renderItem={({ item }) =>
      <ListItemCA
        data={item}
        onLongPress={(title) => {//this **title** return from **onLongPress(data.Title)**
          openModal();
          setTitle(title);// or directly can pass that title in openModal func.
        }}
      />
   } 
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to display data from the long pressed item in the modal, you could add the data as a parameter of your `openModal` function:

```
function openModal(data) {
    // your function
    return (
        <Text>{data.Title}</Text>
    )
}
```

Then, in your `FlatList`, modify the props of `ListItemCA` to call `openModal` for the selected item:

```
renderItem={({ item }) => <ListItemCA data={item} onLongPress={openModal(item)} />}
```

If you also want to save the data from the long pressed item in your `HomePage` component for other uses, you could save it in the state. In your `HomePage` component:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

function HomePage() {
    const [itemData, setItemData] = useState()

    // your code
}
```

Then, in your `flatlist`:

```xml
<FlatList
        data={listData}
        keyExtractor={list => list.Title}
        renderItem={({ item }) => 
            <ListItemCA 
                data={item} 
                onLongPress={ () => {
                    setItemData(item)
                    openModal(item)
                }} 
            /> 
        }
    />
```